# Rephrase Neural Network: Where to Start?

Tags: deep-learning

I'd like to solve the problem that denoted in the below picture.

[image]

With which network could I try and start to solve this problem?

Comment: Please don't use pictures of text as the main description of your problem, it is not searchable, so works against the purpose of the site.